# Bind checkboxes to List in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a `CreateViewModel`.

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
  public AttributesViewModel AttributesInfo { get; set; }
}
```

The `AttributesViewModel` is sent to a partial view.

```
public class AttributesViewModel
{
  public AttributesViewModel()
  {
    ChosenAttributes = new List<int>();
  }

  public List<Attributes> Attributes { get; set; }
  public List<int> ChosenAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

The List of Attributes is outputted in the partial view.  Each one has a checkbox.

```
foreach (var attribute in Model.Attributes)
{
  <input type="checkbox" name="ChosenAttributes" value="@attribute.ID" /> @Attribute.Name
}
```

When I post `CreateViewModel`, `AttributesInfo.ChosenAttributes` is always empty even though I checked some boxes.  How do I properly name each checkbox so that it binds to the ChosenAttributes List?

**My Solution**

I took Stephen Muecke's suggestion to do the two way binding.  So, I created a CheckboxInfo class that contained Value, Text, and IsChecked.  I created a EditorTemplate for it:

```
@model Project.CheckboxInfo

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Text)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Value)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsChecked)&nbsp;@Model.Text
```

One GIANT caveat.  To get this to work properly, I had to create an EditorTemplate for the AttributesViewModel class.  Without it, when CreateViewModel is posted, it cannot link the checkboxes to AttributesInfo.

Answer (score 1):

Your naming the checkbox `name="ChosenAttributes"` but `CreateViewModel` does not contain a property named `ChosenAttributes` (only one named `AttributesInfo`). You may be able make this work using

```
<input type="checkbox" name="AttributesInfo.ChosenAttributes" value="@attribute.ID" /> @Attribute.Name
```

but the correct approach is to use a proper view model that would contain a boolean property (say) `bool IsSelected` and use strongly typed helpers to bind to your properties in a `for` loop or using a custom `EditorTemplate` so that your controls are correctly names and you get 2-way model binding.

Comment: AttributesInfo.ChosenAttributes did not work.  I will try the 2-way binding way.

Comment: Happy to add the code if your having trouble, but why do you have `CreateViewModel` which contains only one property (for `AttributesViewModel`)? - or does it contain other properties you have just omitted)

Comment: Yeah, it contains other properties that I have omitted.  It would have just made it more cumbersome to understand my issue with unimportant properties.

Comment: Then you really need to do this the MVC way and create view models representing what you need to display/edit. In this case you need an `AttributeViewModel` with a property `bool IsSelected` and use `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` to strongly bind to your properties. Something similar to Brendan Vogt's answer. You do not need the `public List<int> ChosenAttributes { get; set; }` property

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a hack like adding an additional parameter in your POST method - `public ActionResult Edit(CreateViewModel model, int[] ChosenAttributes)` (but I would not recommend it)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario, but this was how I did it. The solution is not perfect so please excuse if I have left something out, but you should be able to relate. I tried to simplify your solution as well :)

I changed the `Attribute` class name to `CustomerAttribute`, rename it to whatever you like, use a singular name, not plural. Add a property to your `CustomerAttribute` class, call it whatever you like, I called mine `IsChange`.

```
public class CustomerAttribute
{
     public bool IsChange { get; set; }

     // The rest stays the same as what you have it in your Attributes class

     public string Name { get; set; }  // I'm assuming you have a name property
}
```

Delete your `AttributesViewModel` class, you don't really need it, I like simplicity.

Modify your `CreateViewModel` class to look like this:

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
     public CreateViewModel()
     {
          CustomerAttributes = new List<CustomerAttribute>();
     }

     public List<CustomerAttribute> CustomerAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller will look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel();

     // Populate your customer attributes

     return View(model);
}
```

Your post controller action method would look something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel model)
{
     // Do whatever you need to do
}
```

In your view, you will have something like this:

```
<table>
     <tbody>

          @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CustomerAttributes.Count(); i++)
          {
               <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CustomerAttributes[i].Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.CustomerAttributes[i].IsChange)</td>
               </tr>
          }

     <tbody>
</table>
```

Create a sample app and try out the code above and see if it works for you.